# How do I rewrite a request by hostname unless it is a specified value?

Tags: django, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My app will have a regular domain - let's say example.com - which will have information about logging in, signing up, etc. It will also host numerous other domains dynamically. My app serves the webpage for these at http://example.com/site/foobar.com/

So, I need to redirect all requests where the hostname is not example.com to /site/[hostname]/

I'm writing this in Django and hosting with Apache.

How do I set up a rewrite rule to do this? The user must not know they are on any other site but foobar.com and if the user browses to foobar.com/something - the URL must be rewritten to /site/foobar.com/something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /site/%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [PT]
```

Answer (score 0):

["Dynamic mass virtual hosts with mod_rewrite"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/vhosts.html) covers this. You may want to skip the part where you go to example.com though, and stick to the local filesystem instead.

Comment: Sticking to the local file system won't work. I am taking the hostname from the URL in Django and then my app is serving content based on that.